# Run CMD commands in a loop?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, cmd

I am trying to rename numerous files in a directory (Windows10 laptop) using Python code. I am not finding any error but it is not getting executed. I have recreated the simplified scenario as below.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

data = {'file_1': ['temp112.pptx', 'temp212.pdf', 'temp312.pdf', 'temp412.pptx'], 'file_2': ['mktg.pptx', 'econ.pdf', 'orgg.pdf', 'qtdm.pptx']}
files=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

for index, row in files.iterrows():
    term = "'"+'ren'+' ' + str(row['file_1'] + ' ' + str(row['file_2']+"'"))
    os.system(str(term))
    print(term)

'ren temp112.pptx mktg.pptx'
'ren temp212.pdf econ.pdf'
'ren temp312.pdf orgg.pdf'
'ren temp412.pptx qtdm.pptx'
```

However the term 'ren temp112.pptx mktg.pptx' can be executed manually (os.system('ren temp112.pptx mktg.pptx')). Not sure why it is not executing in a loop.

Comment: [The Windows command prompt is *NOT* a DOS prompt!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54909593/run-dos-commands-in-a-loop)

Comment: Why are you using user commands rather programmers commands. I sure Python can copy it's own files.

Comment: https://www.google.com.au/search?q=python+rename+files ohh the first hit on google - https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-rename-a-file-in-python and surely you would have seen this while looking at the docs for OS.

Comment: Thanks Noodles. I didn't search for this as I was stuck on using the rename command of DOS. Based on your suggestion a small change in the code fixed the issue. (os.rename(row['file_1'], row['file_2]). My actual application was to clean the file names of about 100 pdf docs and it is completed.

Comment: Still don't know why my original attempt failed. For now, it is fine.